# Sql insert with identity vs coalesce max (Id) + 1 insert performance and deadlocks

Tags: sql, deadlock, identity, coalesce

I have a query that uses coalesce max(id) + 1 and then inserts into a table. Which would cause an entire table lock, However I would like to understand if the performance would improve and if I’d have less locks/deadlocks if I just use an identity column instead.

Comment: Any reason you are not already using IDENTITY to begin with?

Comment: So by analogy, you’ve built a house but the roof is a single sheet of tarpaulin and you think a proper roof would improve things. Well, everyone here will assure you **yes, it will** - but where did this initial design come from, why was it approved, and why do you think it _might_ not necessarily be faster or better overall considering that’s exactly what `IDENTITY` is meant for?

Comment: Also… what do you mean by “coalesce max I’d”? Do you mean you have `SomeColumn = COALESCE( MAX( SomeColumn ) + 1, 1 )`? (_yegods_…)

Comment: Unfortunately the table was designed and set up before my time, I just got stuck with it. I’ve recently noticed a lot of deadlocks and pinned it down to the coalesce max(Id) + 1

Comment: . . Basically when a record is being inserted, the maximum Id is retrieved +1 and that is used in the insert. Since I cannot change the original table column to an identity column, my plan is to create a whole new table but with the Id column as identity (max(Id)+1, 1) . . . So the starting number for the identity column will be the max id of the original table +1 and then use a SWITCH TO to copy all the data from the original table to the new one. Then drop the old table and and rename the new table.

Comment: However wouldn’t the insert with the identity also cause an entire table lock or would it reduce the amount of deadlocks and improve performance. My primary issue is the deadlocks.

Comment: _"However wouldn’t the insert with the identity also cause an entire table lock or would it reduce the amount of deadlocks and improve performance."_ - generally speaking, **no**: using `IDENTITY` does not require a table-lock ([but there are rare circumstances where it can happen](https://mohewedy.medium.com/mssql-identity-causes-table-lock-3a13284952ca)) - but normally it won't happen (and that article says using a `SEQUENCE` side-steps the issue entirely, but `IDENTITY` is far simpler than using `SEQUENCE` objects for automatically-generated PKs).